# Why isn't my SR latch working?

Tags: transistors, latch

I built this SR latch out of two NOR gates. However, it doesn't seem to be working for some reason. Why not?

[image]

(Created with TinkerCAD)

Here's a circuit diagram (source is 5 V):

[image]

Comment: these seems 4 transitors, not NORs to me. Well you *can* do a SR with two transistor, however a schematic would be better to follow

Comment: When you press one of the buttons does the 610mV change to more like 200mV on one side?

Comment: Because you have connected the output of each NOR gate directly to the base of another transistor, that base wants to "suck" unlimited amounts of current. I think this circuit *might* still work as a NOR latch, but the voltage difference between high and low logic levels will be very big (0.6V high, 0.2V low). Normally you would put resistors in the collector/base connections

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio Is it alright if I ask how I would do it with two transistors? I know that you can do it with a bistable multivibrator, but from my understanding, that design works when 0 V is "high" and in my case, I need "high" to be a +ve voltage

Comment: @KenEly you can wire the button so that the button pulls Q low instead of activating a transistor which pulls Q low. And same for ~Q

Comment: if you need that polariy then one bjt to invert it's needed. It's far easier with logic gates however, unless it's a learning thing

Comment: I recommend never leaving an input to a logic circuit floating

Comment: @ScottSeidman That's a necessity for CMOS and NMOS. For transistor logic - usually it's not a problem. TTL open input is a high state, always, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The circuit you've shown won't work as shown.

There are two possible variants of it that will work. One uses NMOS FET transistors, like 2N7000:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcKwDa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Another uses NPN transistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f86F7R.png)</sup>

Both circuits could use half as many active devices, without appreciable change in behavior:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH8nfg.png)</sup>

And:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7PttC.png)</sup>

Both circuits suffer from low output drive strength. To improve that, we could use two more devices to have totem-pole outputs, also called super buffers in NMOS terminology.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frRXTF.png)</sup>

And the totem-pole NPN version:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvWGKV.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The second and third transistors must have a base resistors (47k, 100k, etc..).  Otherwise their collectors voltages cannot rise more than 0.7v because they are clamped by opposite transistor BE.